# Error importing data from Excel to access database using VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, excel, ms-access-2007

I have a project desktop application using VB.NET and Access Database. Client requests to me so they can import data customer from Excel to access database. But it contains some errors.

This imports data from Excel to access database:

```
   Sub import()
       DeleteTable()

       Dim i As Integer

       'looping from excel data
       For i = 0 To (objDataTableExcel.Rows.Count - 1)
           Try
               'show data it's save from some coloumn
               With objDataTableExcel.Rows(i)
                   Field1 = .Item(0)
                   Field2 = .Item(1)
                   Field3 = .Item(2)
               End With  'input from variable to table 

           strSQL = "Insert Into " & "[" & Trim(txtTable.Text) & "]" & "(ID , Name , Number) Values " & _

         " (" & Field1 & ",'" & Field2 & "'     ,'" & Field3 & "'); "

           objCommand = New OleDbCommand
           objCommand.Connection = MyConnection.open
           objCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
           objCommand.CommandText = strSQL

           objDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(objCommand)
           objDataAdapter.Fill(objDataSet, "hal_Import")

           MyConnection.close()

       Catch ex As Exception
           'When Err.Number <> 0
           'MsgBox("can't connect to database" & vbCrLf & Err.Description)
           MsgBox(ex.ToString)
           Exit Sub
       End Try
    Next i
    MsgBox("Import Finish", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Import Data")
End Sub
```

and the connection for Excel and access database is at another method. The error show is the connection is **overflow** and this error:

[image]

Comment: Did you initialized your data set with new and give it a table name ? try debugging the code to know where the error is.

Comment: The "Overflow" error usually indicates that you are trying to insert a number that is too large for the field type, e.g., trying to put a number larger than 32767 into an `Integer` field. Check your field types and the values you are trying to insert.

Comment: i have done doit,, and it's work, and another thing is coming, if i want to read the data from excel i parse that to database, but i want read some data with primary key is ID. if data exist i will update and if data not exist in database i will insert that, anyone know about this??